# Rename variously formatted column headers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working on a small tool that does some calculations on a dataframe, let's say something like this:

```
df['column_c'] = df['column_a'] + df['column_b']
```

for this to work the dataframe need to have the columns 'column_a' and 'column_b'. I would like this code to work if the columns are named slightly different named in the import file (csv or xlsx). For example 'columnA', 'Col_a', ect).

The easiest way would be renaming the columns inside the imported file, but let's assume this is not possible. Therefore I would like to do some think like this:

```
if column name is in list ['columnA', 'Col_A', 'col_a', 'a'... ] rename it to 'column_a'
```

I was thinking about having a dictionary with possible column names, when a column name would be in this dictionary it will be renamed to 'column_a'. An additional complication would be the fact that the columns can be in arbitrary order.

How would one solve this problem?

Comment: edited my question to make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

```
for index, column_name in enumerate(df.columns):
    if column_name in ['columnA', 'Col_A', 'col_a' ]:
        df.columns[index] = 'column_a'
```

with dictionary

```
dico = {'column_a':['columnA', 'Col_A', 'col_a' ], 'column_b':['columnB', 'Col_B', 'col_b' ]}
for index, column_name in enumerate(df.columns):
    for name, ex_names in dico:
        if column_name in ex_names:
            df.columns[index] = name
```

Comment: This looks like a neat and compact solution, exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you formulate the conversion logic and write a function accordingly:

```
lst = ['columnA', 'Col_A', 'col_a', 'a']

def converter(x):
    return 'column_'+x[-1].lower()

res = list(map(converter, lst))

['column_a', 'column_a', 'column_a', 'column_a']
```

You can then use this directly in `pd.DataFrame.rename`:

```
df = df.rename(columns=converter)
```

Example usage:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['columnA', 'col_B', 'c'])
df = df.rename(columns=converter)

print(df.columns)

Index(['column_a', 'column_b', 'column_c'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have the list of other names like `list_othername_A` or `list_othername_B`, you can do:

```
for col_name in df.columns:
    if col_name in list_othername_A:
        df = df.rename(columns = {col_name : 'column_a'})
    elif col_name in list_othername_B:
        df = df.rename(columns = {col_name : 'column_b'})
    elif ...
```

EDIT: using the dictionary of @djangoliv, you can do even shorter:

```
dico = {'column_a':['columnA', 'Col_A', 'col_a' ], 'column_b':['columnB', 'Col_B', 'col_b' ]}
#create a dict to rename, kind of reverse dico:
dict_rename = {col:key for key in dico.keys() for col in dico[key]}
# then just rename:
df = df.rename(columns = dict_rename )
```

Note that this method does not work if in `df` you have two columns 'columnA' and 'Col_A' but otherwise, it should work as `rename` does not care if any key in `dict_rename` is not in `df.columns`.

Comment: Yes i could see this work, this would work for renaming one column at a time. But not for renaming multiple columns at ones right?

Comment: @XanderMJ see now with several list of names

Answer (score 1):

This should solve it:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'colA':[1,2], 'columnB':[3,4]})
def rename_df(col):
    if col in ['columnA', 'Col_A', 'colA' ]:
        return 'column_a'
    if col in ['columnB', 'Col_B', 'colB' ]:
        return 'column_b'
    return col
df = df.rename(rename_df, axis=1)
```